# How to run ruby files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Example I have the file test.rb:

```
puts "test test test"
```

How do I run this file in the ruby console?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`load 'test.rb'`

Do you mean Rails console? (Same thing, but the question is tagged rails.)

Answer (score 6):

```
load("test.rb")
```

should do the trick in `irb`.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac you can run in three different ways from the terminal
Method 1
On Terminal irb (Interactive Ruby Shell) for line by line execution then quit command to be out of irb.

Method 2
As ruby is Interpreted language we can run by one command on terminal

1. Save the text editor code with .rb extension.
2. Change the directory in terminal by cd command (cd drag and drop the   folder on terminal so that you can be directed to the directory).
3. ruby hello.rb

Method 3
ruby -v to know the version of ruby
ruby -e 'puts WVU' #line by line execution on terminal

Answer (score 0):

Any ruby file can be run with just `ruby <your_ruby_file.rb>`, supposing that you are in the same directory as the ruby file; If not, just provide a path to the file:

```
ruby path/to/your_file.rb
```